# Java external Process error stream readLine() blocks intermittently

Tags: java, process, stream, blocking, runtime.exec

I am shelling to an external windows program which updates its progress by repeatedly pushing new lines to the error stream.

The command prompt looks something like this when it's running:

```
10% done
10% done
11% done
```

and so forth.

I'm having some success capturing this in my java application thusly:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my little command");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
String s;
while((s = stdError.readLine())!=null)
{
    System.out.println(s);                  
}
```

Unfortunately, as you may have guessed, there's a bit of a problem. The `stdError.readLine()` blocks until there are +- 4000 bytes in the error stream, and only then prints each line out in quick session, before it hangs again.

I've tried changing the `BufferedReader` buffer size, and using `stdError.read(char [] cbuf, int off, int len)`with a small length, to no avail.

How do I fix this hanging issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

> The stdError.readLine() blocks until there are +- 4000 bytes in the error stream

No it doesn't. It returns as soon as there is a line to be read.

What is happening is that the *source process* is buffering its *output,* evidently into 4096-byte chunks. There's nothing you can do about it at the Java end.

Comment: Interesting, how is it then that in the actual command prompt, it is continuously printing?

Comment: Because `stdio` isn't buffered when the output is a terminal.

Comment: The thing is, I'm convinced there is a way, since another closed source program  exists (written in c++, if that's relevant) which definitely shells to the program in question, and is able to provide a fluid progress updates.

Comment: So that program calls `fflush(stderr),` or maybe does whatever it is that disables the buffering, and yours doesn't.